# twilio: raise KeyError(key) from None

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to send a message using twilio and I get the error below. How do I resolve this error?

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['testtest']
auth_token = os.environ['testtesttest']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
                .create(
                     body="Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
                     from_='+16813203595',
                     to='+12345678'
                 )

print(message.sid)
```

```
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'testtest'
```

Comment: The environment variable testest may  not be set up - you need to set that up with your credentials.

Comment: @PaulBrennan How do I set it up?

Answer (score 7):

To easy test your code: A simple fix would be to not use environment variables yet,
Restructure your code to:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'testtest'
auth_token = 'testtesttest'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
                .create(
                     body="Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
                     from_='+16813203595',
                     to='+12345678'
                 )

print(message.sid)
```

Once pleased then consider and you get a response from twilio you can switch to env variables

Answer (score 6):

For anyone in the future if you want the simple answer to this question.

In Twilio's sample code it has these two lines

```
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
```

You don't actually place your Twilio account sid and token in these lines. KEEP THEM AS THEY ARE. Do not change these lines. Do not add your account sid and your token. Instead at the command prompt type in:

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=your_SID_account
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=your_auth_token
```

Now run the script and the script will pull your environmental keys. Keeps your info safe this way :)

Comment: This worked for me. A couple of important notes: (1) It's recommended to put these export statements into `~/.bash_profile` file (2) If you are using an IDE (e.g. PyCharm), make sure to restart it; otherwise, it won't be able to retrieve the values of these environment variables.

Comment: "Instead at the command prompt type in:..."

 when I run CMD and type this in, I get "'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Am I being dumb?

Comment: @JohnMorrison I'm going to guess that you are on Windows? Environmental variables are different on Windows. If you confirm you are on Windows, I'll send you instructions on how to use environmental variables on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up environment variables is operating system dependent.

Here is a list of the links depending on the machine you are using

1. Windows 10 https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10
2. Linux https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/
3. Mac https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x

You will also need to set up your twilio account and have both your `account_sid` and `auth_token` from them

Answer (score 1):

Just assign value as you would do to any other dict!

```
account_sid=os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']='value of sid'
auth_token=os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']='value of auth token'
```